# Voice to text conversion : Help on opening a file through converted text and minimizing and maximizing an application

Tags: c#

The project is in c#

Process.Start(@"D:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\"+textBox1.Text+".exe");
It displays "cannot find the path specified.

Actually i am working on a project that converts voice to text and executes the applications through the converted text..

I am not able to find any way of maximizing and minimizing the application and opening it

Can you please suggest me some other way to open the file or correct me if i am terribly wrong here..
It will be really helpful for me to complete my project in  C# i am a final year student
Thanx in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

if you use:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.WindowStyle=ProcessWindowStyle.xxx
```

you can choose if start process maximized, normal or not...
Are you sure the exe is right in directory you're running it?